# Kate autoindent is off, but it keeps autoindenting

Tags: kate

I'm running Kate under Gnome, in Maverick.

After the last Ubuntu update ran, the "enter" key started acting strangely in Kate. I'm *guessing* it's trying to auto-indent even though I have auto-indent off.

Settings:
[image: settings]

But when I'm in a CSS file, and I hit the "enter" key once, the cursor jumps down 2 lines, and indents 3 spaces.

I just use Kate as a text editor (I use it because it has the best syntax highlighting) and I'm at a loss. Any suggestions/ideas are very welcome.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Under *Open/Save → Modes & Filetypes* you'll find that the *Markup/CSS* filetype has an indentation profile assigned.

All filetypes that don't follow the system default will use their indentation mode no matter what you set in the preferences. Fortunately you can just change it to whatever you like (e.g., *None*).

Comment: THANK you! That's been driving me bananas. I really appreciate it - that worked beautifully.

Comment: I have Kate 18.12 (Under KDE Plasma / openSUSE) and even with that it still indents.